# Data binding in windows forms or WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have the following:
    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

When I add to the parameter list, to make:
    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, Class c)
then it will cause all sorts of problems.  However, I need really want in my main:

```
Class c = new Class();
```

And then I would like to click a button so that ButtonClick is called, but I really need access to the "Class c" in the function body, so I really need

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, Class c)
```

to compile somehow.

I have tried other ways around the issue, such as making Class static, but it would create too much refactoring and cause other errors.

I don't know if this will be possible in Windows Forms.  I am not opposed to switching over to XAML and WPF, I just want to know that doing something such as

```
private void ButtontClick(object sender, EventArgs e, Class c)
```

will be possible.

Comment: From where, you are passing instance of  Class c ?

Comment: Contrary to the title you wrote, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with data-binding. The marked duplicate answers the question text you wrote. In your case, you can subscribe to the `Click` event like this: `button1.Click += (sender, e) => ButtonClick(sender, e, c);`.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `Class c` variable a member variable in your main class where your `ButtonClick` event handler is located.  Unless this `ButtonClick` event handler is your own custom event handler, you can't add more parameters to the framework's `Click` event handler for a button.  You will have to access your `Class c` variable as a member variable or use commands and command bindings with command parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `c` in the `Button.Tag` property and use `((Button)sender).Tag` in the click event handler to get it.